# How do I delete meshes?

Tags: mesh

I don't know how to delete meshes. I know I can create them using the create tool but I'm not sure how to delete objects. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to select the object you want to delete. Then you can click delete on the tool tab or you can use your shortcut which is x and select delete.